# How to submodule a larger project and add few files to it?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I would like to create a git repository that has submodule of a larger project and just add a few files to it.

For example, I would like to create a new repository that submodules this repository https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack and just adds a single file in `bin/steps`.

At the moment the way I do this is I clone the entire `python-buildpack` repository and add a single file to it in `bin/steps`. This way if there are changes to the `python-buildpack` then I have to individually get them.

What would be the best way to submodule this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do what you want to do with submodules.

> Submodules, like subtrees, aim to reuse code from another repo
>   somewhere inside your own repo’s tree.

(from [here](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407#.cwu65o6vk))

This is the sole purpose of submodules: Reuse a certain state of another repository as a sub-repository of your own repository. You can not, however, use submodules to add files from your parent repository into the submodule.